# JSON get value of children property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash

I am making an API call and returning some data back. The issue I am running into is accessing the second level of the JSON "logos_here []". The goal is to return only the url data from all the objects. I have attached the data and what I am using now that is even getting me close.

Data Here

```
{
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "metadata": {
                "logos_here": [
                    {
                        "logo1": {
                            "url": "https://cosmicjs.com/upload/logo1.jpg",
                            "imgix_url": "https://cosmicjs.imgix.net/logo1.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "logo2": {
                            "url": "https://cosmicjs.com/upload/logo2.jpg",
                            "imgix_url": "https://cosmicjs.imgix.net/logo2.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "logo3": {
                            "url": "https://cosmicjs.com/upload/logo3.jpg",
                            "imgix_url": "https://cosmicjs.imgix.net/logo3.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "logo4": {
                            "url": "https://cosmicjs.com/upload/logo4.jpg",
                            "imgix_url": "https://cosmicjs.imgix.net/logo4.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "logo5": {
                            "url": "https://cosmicjs.com/upload/logo5.jpg",
                            "imgix_url": "https://cosmicjs.imgix.net/logo5.jpg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code Here

```
var response_json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
var page = response_json.data.object;
var main_image = page.metadata.logos_here;

function listData(main_image) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  $.each(main_image, function(key, val) {
    html += "</br>";
    if (typeof val === "object")
      html += listData(val);
    else
      html += val;
    html += "</br>";
  });
  html += "</ul>";
  return html;
};

$(listData(main_image)).appendTo("body");
```

What I would like to extract just the "url" values and display them in a li. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes that each object in the `logos_here` array just contains one property. It uses `Object.keys()` to get that property name, then uses that to get the object and its `url` property.

```
function listData(main_image) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  $.each(main_image, function(index, val) {
    var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
    var url = val[key].url;
    html += "<li>" + url + "</li>";
  });
  html += "</ul>";
  return html;
};
```

If there can be multiple properties in each object, you can use a nested loop.

```
function listData(main_image) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  $.each(main_image, function(index, val) {
    $.each(val, function(key, obj) {
      html += "<li>" + obj.url + "</li>";
    });
  });
  html += "</ul>";
  return html;
};
```

Comment: Isn't `val` an object that contains `"logo1"`, `"logo2"`, etc? It doesn't directly contain `"url"`

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the extra level of nesting.

Comment: I almost missed it myself! I've been staring at this for a few minutes. For reasons.

Comment: Why is it returning an array of objects with different keys, instead of a single object with multiple keys?

Comment: I've updated the code to get the single property within the object.